# How to access document URL from a DocumentChooserBlock in Wagtail Streamfield?

Tags: wagtail-streamfield

I am trying to access the URL to a document uploaded into a wagtail streamfield but URL is blank.

Using {{page.document.url}} with a block doesn't work.

This is what I use in my model and then in the panel it is defined a DocumentChooserBlock()

```
document = models.ForeignKey( 'wagtaildocs.Document', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+' )
```

Uploading a file would help displaying it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to this. I was using the wrong tags. Because we are working with blocks {{page.document.url}} doesn't work but {{block.value.url}} does.